# Finding the closest int/float key in a dictionary to a specific int/float

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to find the closest int/float key in a dictionary to a specific int/float variable. I have tried:

```
record = {1:370,2:45,5:87}
binum = ''
t = raw_input("")
memory = [("hi", "lee"), ("lee", "ma"), ("ma","bree")]
bi2 = ''
bi = []
def b(): 
  words = t.split()

  result = list(zip(words, words[1:]))
  print result

  for x in memory:
    global bi2
    global bi

    if(x in result):
      bi.append("1")

    else:
      bi.append("0")

   print bi    
   bi2 = ''.join(bi)
   print bi2

   dec = int(bi2, 2)
   print dec
   print(min(record, key = lambda x:abs(record[x]-dec)))

b()
```

I want it to return 5, but it gives a type error. The error is:

> TypeError: 'key' is an invalid keyword argument for this function on line 36 in main.py

Is there something I am missing? A better way to do this?

Comment: Please provide the _full_ traceback, not just the name of the error please.

Comment: According to your error, you overwrote the built-in `min` somewhere in your code. Can you post your full code?

Comment: Probably you've re-defined `min` somewhere in your code. With standard build-ins your code works fine